# Can this C program , that uses purely an unlinked C stdlib and is compiled for Linux, run on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

The question is a bit specific, so assume the following:

1. The program's C source code does not explicitly use platform-specific functions (it does not explicitly use system calls, for example).
2. To interact with the OS, the source code uses the C stdlib.
3. The stdlib is not linked at compile time.
4. The program was compiled for Linux on a machine running Linux, then moved to another machine running Windows.
5. Before executing the program on Windows, the Linux executable is (somehow) converted to a format compatible with Windows.
6. Both machines have the same hardware.
7. Both machines have a implementation of the C stdlib.

Now for the question(s):

1. Given all the assumptions above, can the program execute on Windows? If not, why?
2. If there's an assumption that is incorrect, why is that?

Comment: The point 5 seems weird to me : have you got such a tool ? Such a tool would need a mapping : this shared-object should be replaced by this dynamic link library, and since both libraries have not exactly the same functions, there would be an issue if you use unsupported functions. It is not simply converting ELF format to EXE.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I don't know of any such tool. But given a simple program, that prints some text to the terminal, is it possible to convert one format to another (no matter how difficult it may be) and successfully execute it? 

I'm interested in what makes a program compiled for a certain OS incompatible on another. I know that executable formats are one of the reasons why they are incompatible, but I assume that there must be a way to convert from one format to another. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

The binaries on Windows and Linux have very different format, so one cannot
run on the other. Linux shared libraries are not at all the same
as Windows DLL.

Cross-system execution is achieved by either of:

- Re-compilation for the target system (many compilers are capable
  of compiling on system A for execution on B)
- Running on an emulator, such as
  [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/), CrossOver and others
- Running in a virtual machine, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL),
  Docker or similar.

Comment: If you want to understand this further, start by looking at the differences between the ***PE format*** and the ***ELF format***.  They are very different.  Some things better on one side.. some better on the other.  If you do, prepare to be bombarded with OS bigotry but you will come out knowing *why* converting it isn't a simple task.  I believe that nothing like this is impossible.. just pointless and not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

No. The executable format of Linux is not compatible with Windows.  You would have to recompile the program for Windows.

Alternatively, you could run the program natively in the Windows Subsystem for Linux or in a Virtual Machine running Linux.